# Stream and run Managed.Dll?

Tags: c#, dll

Let's say I have a want to make a licesing system where my user authecticates against my ASP.Net website from my desktop application.
Would it than be possible to stream a Managed .Dll (C# .Dll) File or .Exe I guess and make it run on my Clients Computer without saving the file to disk? 
So when my User stops using it he should not have access to the file.

If so what should I look into to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Browser security don't allow you to do this. 
But you can use a litle exe which download lib, and using reflection load it and run.